# Temporary ASP.NET Files in TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, teamcity

I had a problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7047260/631796) , and most of the articles online suggested me to remove "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder located in Microsoft .NET Framework folder. However, those folders are always empty. I suppose that is because I am using TeamCity for builds.

Is the folder mentioned in different location when I use TeamCity for build agent?

Comment: have you checked that the folder actually exists? It seems to me that either the folder or the .dll is missing

Comment: Folder and dll exist whan I get that error.

Comment: personally what I do with my CI projects is to keep the dependency dlls as part of the checkout (and in source control where appropriate) as this means this type of issue will not happen. Is there a chance that the build is looking at a different path since your issues?

Comment: Our dependency DLLs are also part of our source repository, and the path specified in error is as supposed. Suprisingly, TeamCity succeeded building the solution a couple of times, even though I changed absolutely nothing :(

Comment: ok this drives me to the question - you no longer get this issue or you only get it sometimes? Do you have more than 1 build agent?

Comment: I still get it sometimes, and i have only 1 build agent which is same as build server.

Comment: @Ottomanlast let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2450/discussion-between-stack72-and-ottomanlast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said from chat - it seems to me that the Windows 7 and .Net 4 SDK is not installed correctly

resgen.exe is part of that sdk. therefore install this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/dlx/en-us/listdetailsview.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b and try again

let me know how it goes

Comment: I assume you are right. However, I reinstalled the build server from stratch and problem fixed. Thanks for your help.